# I can't get the value from my checkBoxes, I need to print the value on the checkbox under the submit button into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, user-input

```
  <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
      <label for="selectmenu" class="select">Preferred Seating:</label> <!-- Following drop down checkbox -->
      <select name="selectmenu" id="selectmenu">
        <option name="selectmenu" value="200" id="lowerArea" >Lower Area($200)</option>
        <option name="selectmenu" value="150" checked="checked" id="levelOne">Level 1($150)</option>
        <option name="selectmenu" value="100" id="levelTwo">Level 2($100)</option>
        <option name="selectmenu" value="200" id="balcony">Balcony($200)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <!--End of DropDownBoxes-->
    <!--START OF CHECK BOXES-->

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">

        <legend>Prefered night:</legend>
     <input type="radio" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_0" class="custom" value=""  checked="checked" /></option>
        <label for="checkbox1_0">Thursday</label>
        <br />
            <input type="radio" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_1" class="custom" value="" />
                <label for="checkbox1_1">Friday</label>
                <br><!--Break as on Example-->
                    <input type="radio" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_2" class="custom" value="" />
                    <label for="checkbox1_2">Saturday</label>
      </fieldset><!-- Above are check boxes -->
    </div> 

    <!--END OF CHECK BOXES-->
<!--Put a tick box here that asks for weekly mail-->
         <button type="submit" value="Register" onClick="validateGalaOrder()"></button>
            <p id="OrderInput"></p><!--USERS INPUT RETURNS TO THIS <P>-->
            <p id="tktCost"></p>
            <p id="orderErrorMsg"></p><!--INCORRECT INPUT MESSAGES RETURN TO THIS <P>-->
```

There are suppose to be breaks inbetween the check boxes, at the moment I can't get the 'saturday' variable to print!

```
    function validateGalaOrder() {
var orderErrorMsg = "";         
var OrderInput = "";    
var ValidateOrderName = document.getElementById('txtOrderName').value;
var numTickets = document.getElementById('numTickets').value;
var Orderemail = document.getElementById('txtOrderEmail');      
var filter =  /*Email Symbol and letter Validator*/  /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;//This filters out the email input

var lowerLvl = document.getElementById('lowerArea').value;
var lvlOne = document.getElementById('levelOne').value;
var lvlTwo= document.getElementById('levelTwo').value;
var Balcony =  document.getElementById('balcony').value;
var cost = '';

var prefNight;


 if(ValidateOrderName.length <= 2){
            orderErrorMsg += ("<b>-ERROR- Please enter a valid name with a length of at least 3 letters</b>");
            document.getElementById('orderErrorMsg').innerHTML = orderErrorMsg;
                document.getElementById('txtOrderName').value = '';//will clear input field if false.
                    document.getElementById('txtOrderName').focus();//this Focuses on textbox if input is wrong. 
                            //alert("-ERROR- Please enter a name more than one letter!"); 
                document.getElementById('OrderInput').innerHTML = '';//If someone decides to change there input and that changed input is wrong then this will clear the other data from under the button and just show the error message

        return false;
    } 


  if (!filter.test(Orderemail.value)) {
            orderErrorMsg += ("<b>-ERROR- Please provide a valid email address.</b>");  
            document.getElementById('orderErrorMsg').innerHTML = orderErrorMsg;
                document.getElementById('txtOrderEmail').value = '';
                     document.getElementById('txtOrderEmail').focus();//this Focuses on textbox if input is wrong.   
                            // alert('Please provide a valid email address');
                document.getElementById('OrderInput').innerHTML = '';//If someone decides to change there input and that changed input is wrong then this will clear the other data from under the button and just show the error message
        return false;
    }  

    if(numTickets <= 0){
        orderErrorMsg += ("<b>-ERROR- Please enter an amount of tickets greater than zero</b>");
        document.getElementById('orderErrorMsg').innerHTML = orderErrorMsg;
            document.getElementById('numTickets').value = '';
                document.getElementById('numTickets').focus();//this Focuses on textbox if input is wrong.
                        /*alert("-ERROR- Please enter a mobile number with exactly 10 numeric digits");*/
                document.getElementById('OrderInput').innerHTML = '';//If someone decides to change there input and that changed input is wrong then this will clear the other data from under the button and just show the error message
        return false;
    }


        if(document.getElementById('checkbox1_0').checked == true){
            prefNight = 'Thursday';
        }
            if(document.getElementById('checkbox1_1').checked == true){
                prefNight = 'Friday';
            }
                if(document.getElementById('checkbox1_2').checked == true){
                prefNight = 'saturday';
                }




    else{
            cost = parseInt(document.getElementById('selectmenu').value,10) * numTickets;  //This calculates the cost
            var Orderemail = document.getElementById('txtOrderEmail').value;
         OrderInput += ("Thank You " + "<b>"+ValidateOrderName+"</b>" + " For ordering your tickets" + "<br /> <br />" + "Number of tickets ordered: " + "<b>" + numTickets +"</b>" +
        "<br>" + "Your email is: " + "<b>" + Orderemail + "</b>" + "<br /> The total cost will be: "+ "<b>$"+ cost + "</b>" + prefNight);
                document.getElementById('OrderInput').innerHTML = OrderInput;//This prints the users details.
                    document.getElementById('orderErrorMsg').innerHTML = '';

    }   
    return true;

}
```

Hi guys I have updated my code and basically at the moment I can print 'Thursday' and 'Friday' But I cannot print 'Saturday'!

Comment: kindly post your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: You are not using jQuery, did you add it as a tag because you consider using it or was that a mistake?

Comment: @Esa Usually people who know jquery are good with javascript :).

Comment: @Arvind I have now edited my post, The only problem Im having now is not being able to print the 'saturday' checkbox if it is selected

Comment: @JamesW jQuery IS javascript, I was simply asking because nowdays alot of people thing jQuery and javascript are the same thing and I didn't know if you were one of those. Also don't use tags that are not relevant, jQuery is not used in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using radio buttons instead of check boxes!

```
<input type="radio" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_2" class="custom" value="" />
```

Instead it should be

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_2" class="custom" value="" />
```

For radio buttons with id "checkbox1_2" you can use-

```
var rates = document.getElementById('checkbox1_2').value;
```

to see whether it is checked or not  you can use--

```
var checked=document.getElementById('checkbox1_2').checked;
```

or by jquery

```
$('input[name=checkbox1]:checked').val();
```

Comment: thanks a lot! :). Worked well.Do you know any good websites where I can check out this type of javascript?

Comment: Stackoverflow.com ! :)

Comment: Haha yeah definitely the best ! @RahulB I have posted an updated answer Below.

Answer (score 0):

These are my Radio Buttons( I have changed them from checkboxes ):

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">

        <legend>Prefered night:</legend>
     <input type="radio" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_0" class="custom" value=""  checked="checked" /></option>
        <label for="checkbox1_0">Thursday</label>
        <br />
            <input type="radio" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_1" class="custom" value="" />
                <label for="checkbox1_1">Friday</label>
                <br /><!--Break as on Example-->
                    <input type="radio" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_2" class="custom" value="" />
                    <label for="checkbox1_2">Saturday</label>
      </fieldset><!-- Above are check boxes -->
    </div>
```

Here is the Javascript that is printing the checked radio button's value ( I have made a variable and used if statements to decide what variable(Answer) to use ), I have put my ***IF STATEMENTS*** in the else{ } section because that is where all my correct inputs go. Please bare in mind that my variables are all above this else statement( OR in the previous question ):

```
else{

        //Below is the checkbox printing
                if(document.getElementById('checkbox1_0').checked == true){
            prefNight = 'Thursday';
        }
            if(document.getElementById('checkbox1_1').checked == true){
                prefNight = 'Friday';
            }
                if(document.getElementById('checkbox1_2').checked == true){
                    prefNight = 'Saturday';
                }
        //Above is the checkbox printing

            cost = parseInt(document.getElementById('selectmenu').value,10) * numTickets;//This calculates the cost(selectMenu*numTickets)
            var Orderemail = document.getElementById('txtOrderEmail').value;//This will grab the email value Inputed.
         OrderInput += ("Thank You " + "<b>"+ValidateOrderName+"</b>" + " For ordering your tickets" + "<br /> <br />" + "Number of tickets ordered: " + "<b>" + numTickets +"</b>" +
        "<br>" + "Your email is: " + "<b>" + Orderemail + "</b>" + "<br /> The total cost will be: "+ "<b>$"+ cost + "</b>" + prefNight);
                document.getElementById('OrderInput').innerHTML = OrderInput;//This prints the users details to a html element.
                    document.getElementById('orderErrorMsg').innerHTML = '';//Removes error messages when everything is correct.

    }   
    return true;
```